# Thanos is not the only one to wield 2 infinity stones

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, the-avengers, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the very first few minutes Ebony Maw presents Thanos with the space stone and says to him that no one has ever had the power and honor to wield 2 infinity stones at the same time.

Is this a mistake? In the first Avengers movie, Loki DID. He received the scepter that contained the mind stone (which we only discovered during "Age of Ultron") from Thanos himself, in the hopes that Loki would bring back the space stone from earth. Loki wielded both stones for the entire movie.

The question is, am I missing something? Is Ebony Maw wrong? Hard to imagine that being the case, since Thanos was deeply involved in Loki's actions in the first Avengers movie. Is this an oversight by the writers? Has there been any explanation for this?

Comment: Well, I think Loki didn't know there was an infinity stone in his scepter, but could be that Ebony Maw was just being a bootlicker...

Comment: Technically speaking, Loki wasn't *wielding* the Space Stone. He had the Tesseract, but I don't believe he ever used it.

Comment: @F1Krazy he opened a giant space portal with it, I think that counts. He used the mind stone to control people's minds as well.

Comment: He gives the Tesseract to Erik Selvig to build into a device that opens a portal.  This is a long way from having the stone in a gauntlet and directly commanding it to transport you around.  Its pedantic to argue over the meaning of the word "wield" ... it could mean own, or it could mean to directly command - the main thing is that Ebony Maw is happy to give his boss the credit.  This doesn't make it an inconsistency at all.

Comment: ...and it seems likely that Thanos couldn't "wield" the stones until he had the Gauntlet. Hold sure but actually use properly...that's not clear, I think.

Comment: In addition, it is possible that Ebony Maw was wrong. We don't know what he was doing before Infinity War and we know that Thanos gives special missions to some of his Children (Gamora searching for the Soul Stone for example) and that they are not constantly together. It is possible that Ebony Maw is not aware of the details of the events of the Avengers (the first movie).

Comment: @Taladris or doing a bit of marketing bullish—.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Loki didn't control 2 stones.

While Loki used the Mind Stone though the Scepter on Hawkeye, the SHIELD Agents and Erik Selvig, he didn't use the Space Stone himself. Rather, he had Selvig build a machine to open the portal over New York and the Tesseract was activated through *that* by Selvig, not Loki, so if you was to count using the Tesseract though the machine as "using the space stone" then Selvig used it.

In fact, when Loki first appeared, Nick Fury attempted to escape with the Tesseract while Loki was giving out his speech, first putting on a glove to remove it from the machine they had it in and putting it in that suitcase.

[image: Nick Fury taking the tesseract out]

But when Loki stops him and goes to escape, it's Selvig who's carrying the Suitcase.

From there, we can assume that Tesseract never left the suitcase until Selvig's machine was built.

So this means Ebony Maw is correct, Thanos is the first to wield 2 infinity stones at the same time, *himself*.

Comment: Great detailed answer friend, and having rewatched the specific scenes you are correct.

Comment: In addition to that, the stone had to be freed from the tesseract to be at full potency.  Anyone using either the staff or the tesseract were not truly using the stone because their housings were diffusing the power in such a way that mere mortals could handle them to some degree.  What Thanos does with the Space stone is far more than Selvig could ever do with the tesseract.